# REGEXP to get column values which contains number greater than 200000

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a requirement where there is a column EVENTNAME which may contain texts like BIRTHDAY but also for a special OFFER event it will contain only digits.
And I need to sort two different types of offer one of which is less than 200000 and the rest greater than 200000.

Can somebody help with some REGEXP_LIKE?

Comment: Give us a sample of values you have in that column.

Comment: There are Strings like `BIRTHDAY`, `ANNIVERSARY`, `NEW_GIFT` while there are only numbers which are 6 char long like `100060` or `200001`. I need to get those rows with number only and values greater than `200000`

Comment: So digits only and no other character?

Comment: Can you please edit the question instead of writing important information here as a comment.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Use `regexp_substr()`, convert to a decimal, and do the comparison:

```
where to_number(regexp_substr(eventname, '[0-9]+')) >= 200000
```

Answer (score 2):

`\D` matches nondigit characters, so you can do this:

```
with t(id, eventname) as (
    select 1, 'BIRTHDAY' from dual union all
    select 2, '4040404'  from dual union all
    select 3, '404'      from dual union all
    select 4, '404 PQR'  from dual union all
    select 5, 'NAMEDAY'  from dual )
select t.*, 
       case 
         when regexp_like(eventname, '\D')  then 'OTHER'
         when to_number(eventname) > 200000 then 'OFFER OVER 200'
         else 'OFFER BELOW 200'
       end type
  from t
```

Result:

```
    ID EVENTNAME TYPE
------ --------- ---------------
     1 BIRTHDAY  OTHER
     2 4040404   OFFER OVER 200
     3 404       OFFER BELOW 200
     4 404 PQR   OTHER
     5 NAMEDAY   OTHER
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexp_like` to find such entries and `to_number` to convert such entries to number for comparison:

```
SELECT str, CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(str, '^\d{1,6}$') THEN CASE
        WHEN TO_NUMBER(str) >= 200000 THEN 'more than 200000'
        ELSE 'less than 200000'
    END
    ELSE str
END AS x_type
FROM (
    SELECT 'Birthday' AS str FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '200001' FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT '200000' FROM DUAL
) tests
```